# JsonArray loop using Streams

Tags: java, gson

I'm trying to loop a JsonArray using Streams in java, I have looped a JsonObject Using the following code

```
jsonObject.entrySet().stream()
```

but there isn't no `entrySet()` class for JsonArray, How ever I tried using the iterator method but it only printed out one of the JsonObject inside of the JsonArray here is my attempt

```
.map(JsonArray::iterator)
.map(Iterator::next)
.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Edit: I'm getting the JsonArray from a JsonObject stream

```
.map(JsonArray.class::cast)
//need to handle jsonArray
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `StreamSupport.stream(jsonArray.spliterator(), false)` to get a `Stream` of json array.

So your code will look like:-

```
StreamSupport.stream(jsonArray.spliterator(), false)
             .forEach(....);
```

Comment: I'm getting the JsonArray using Map inside an existed stream. can you tell me how I can achieve that using it?

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: I wan't to do it inside the existing stream, How do I achieve this?

Comment: It just prints out the whole JsonArray I already tried that, I need to loop inside the JsonArray

Answer (score 1):

These are the utility functions which converts iterator into stream. use these functions to covert your iterator into streams.

```
public static <T> Stream<T> asStream(Iterator<T> sourceIterator) {
    return asStream(sourceIterator, false);
  }

  public static <T> Stream<T> asStream(Iterator<T> sourceIterator, boolean parallel) {
    Iterable<T> iterable = () -> sourceIterator;
    return StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), parallel);
  }
```

like :

```
asStream(jsonObject.keys())
   .map(JsonObject::getJSONObject)
   .foreach(//do what you want);
```

OR

```
asStream(jsonObject.keys()).forEach();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jsonObject.entrySet().stream()
                .map(entery -> {
                    return StreamSupport.stream(((JsonArray) entery.getValue()).spliterator(), false);
                })
                .forEach(stream->stream.forEach(System.out::println));
```

Using stream support you can map/convert your jsonArray to stream and then in forEach you get the stream for each jsonArray then you can stream them in that forEach

Comment: I don't want to loop a jsonObject I wanna loop a JsonArray, entry.getValue() isn't an option for me when I am using a jsonArray

Comment: can you post your code as your clearly saying in previous comment on @Kartik answer that you want to loop in existing stream so i thought that it will be the jsonObject entrySet stream